# Dynamically resize columns based on how many there are in a row

Tags: html, css, dynamic-columns

I'm trying to make a responsive column layout that resizes depending on the number of columns.

[Link to JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wewheagw/2/)

HTML:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="box half">1/2</div>
<div class="box quarter">1/4</div>
<div class="box quarter">1/4</div>
</div>

<div class="row">
<div class="box half">1/2</div>
<div class="box quarter hidden">1/4</div>
<div class="box quarter">1/4</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.clearfix:before, .row:before, .clearfix:after, .row:after {
content:" ";
display: table;
}
.clearfix:after, .row:after {
clear: both;
}
.row {
margin-bottom: 20px;
width: 100%;
text-align: left;
}
.row .box {
background: #fff;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
-ms-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
box-shadow: 0 1px 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
float: left;
height: 100px;
}
.row .box.half {
width: 50%;
}
.row .box.quarter {
width: 25%;
}
.hidden {
display: none;
}
```

So, what I'm trying to do is if I add the class "hidden" to one of the boxes, the other boxes will resize and fill up the row. For example, in the first row we have one column 50% and two columns 25%; If I hide one 25% column, the first column will have 66% and the 2nd one will have 33%.

I have to do this without adding any other classes to html and work in IE8+.

Comment: Please include the HTML and CSS in the question, preferably in a snippet. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I don't think that's possible with pure CSS, you'll need some javascript most likely.

Comment: Does "without adding any other classes to html" include dynamically adding those with JS?

Comment: yes, I can use JS/jQuery.

Answer (score -2):

You can use [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries). Add this to your style sheets.

```
@media (max-width: 600px) {
    .row .box.half {
        width: 66%;
    }
    .row .box.quarter {
        width: 33%;
    }
    .row .box.quarter:last-child {
        display: none;
    }
}
```